# Increase PHP Memory on Wordpress powered by Openshift

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, openshift

[Open Shift WP-Config file version of Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YxzH.jpg)

[Wordpress WooCommerce Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxUj2.jpg)

Hello,

I am using a wordpress powered site hosted on Openshift. I am running woocommerce, which is an ecommerce plugin along with it. So far, users are able to access the shop, add items to their cart as well as shipping.

However, come time to checkout, the site just freezes.

From searching online, the best best was increase the PHP memory allocation.

I was able to do so, after extensive search, by creating local ssh keys, which I used to point the openshift console to the site. Now FTP works.

However, when I access the WP-Config which is supposed to let me increase the memory, I can do it.

According to the codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP:

> Increase PHP Memory to 64MB
>
> define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' ); Increase PHP Memory to 96MB
>
> define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );

I also upgraded to the "Free" Bronze plan to see if that would help.

Thus, any and all suggestion is most welcome.

Also, I am having some issues with the getting the domain to display properly. I bought the name through GoDaddy. However, I will leave this for another discussion. I found some thread here for it, and will try those later.

The cart and it been able to be checked out is my priority.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you getting any php errors?

Comment: You may need to use a larger gear size for your application, what size are you currently using?

Comment: @corey112358: I have the free 1GB gear storage allocation. I was hoping to keep it free.

Comment: @JamesJones: No, I don't see any error per se, the cart just would not check out, and the PHP file would doesn't display any line for me to adjust the memory limit.

Comment: 1GB refers to the amount of storage, the small gear gives you 512MB of memory, which probably is not enough.

Comment: So, you don't think I'll be able to increase the memory even just to 64 MB by editing the files?

Comment: Can you get access to the php.ini file? What memory is set there?

Comment: I couldn't located the PHP.ini file. Do you know the path that I can use to located it? I could find the htc access though - http://s16.postimg.org/ubsqx9thh/access.jpg

Comment: Re your comment: 'the PHP file would doesn't display any line for me to adjust the memory limit'. Have you tried adding there a new line somewhere on top (but after `<?php`) `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M')` (or 96)? It seems the memory limit is then set by `default-constants.php` either to 40 or 64 MB, if not set explicitly otherwise.

Comment: Hey everyone,  thank you for all the help. I found a solution, which was rather unexpected.

Comment: The site domain comes from GoDaddy, and so when I chose the option to forward the generic Openshift domain, without masking, it solves this issue.

However, the odd thing is that now the after users go to my custom domain name, if they are careful, they will notice that the address in the URL navigation bar quickly revert to the generic Openshift apps name.

I'm not sure what the policy is here on StackOver Flow for following up on questions, so I should probably stop here for this question. Thank you for the help.

Hopefully I'll be able to fix the URL display name sometimes soon !

Comment: @Joel : were you able to fix the memory issue though? Would love it if you submitted an answer to your question with the fix that worked for you.